# Combinatorics: stars and bars with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

How do you solve $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \le 45$, where all the $x$'s are nonnegative with the added conditions that $x_1 \ge 0, x_2\ge 1, x_3 \ge 4,$ and $x_4 \le 5$? I know how to do the normal stars and bars argument, but the inequality and these conditions make it more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using slack variables.  Find the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=45$, where each $x_i$ is a non-negative integer.  That converts the last inequality into an equality.

For $x_2$ and $x_3$, just use the constraints as your starting point:  $x_1+y_2+y_3+x_4+x_5 = 40$, where $y_2+1=x_2$ and $y_3+4=x_3.$

To handle the inequality on $x_4$, use the technique discussed above to ascertain the number of solutions of your original equation where $x_4 \geq 6:  x_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+x_5=34,$ where $y_4+6=x_4$.  Subtract this number from the number of solutions of your first equation.

Thus, your answer should be $\binom{44}{4}-\binom{38}{4}.$

Answer (score 1):

I think of this as the number of ways to place at most $45$ indistinguishable balls in $4$ distinct buckets, where we must place at least $1$ ball in bucket $2$, at least $4$ balls in bucket $3$, and at most $5$ balls in bucket $4$.

First, add a fifth bucket, and place $45$ balls in the buckets, so that there will be at most $45$ in the first $4$.  Start by putting $1$ ball in bucket $2$ and $4$ in bucket $3$, leaving us with $40$ balls to place.  If we place $k$ balls in bucket $4$, we must place $40-k$ balls in the remaining $4$ buckets.  By stars and bars, there are $\binom{43-k}3$ ways to do this, so the answer is $$\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{43-k}{3}$$

Comment: I figured out how to avoid the casework.

Comment: @RobertShore Very nice.